# Show Nav menu on minimize screen

Tags: html, css

I have a side menu that i want to be show just when the user minimize the screen : (And will also appear on cell phones)

```
<button class="???" onclick="toggleMenu()">☰</button>
```

How can i do it ?

Comment: Have you tried using media queries?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make use of CSS media screen queries here to make sure your menu can account for smaller and larger screen sizes.

I'd recommend looking at something like Bootstrap or similar libraries to help you along the road with that.

Good link for reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors

If you don't want to use Bootstrap and would rather make your own CSS classes to handle this, you'll have to experiment with examples such as this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: MDN is usually a better resource than w3schools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries. w3schools can often be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @GalaxyCat105, updated based on that :)